# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello

Tags: python, django

Django version = 1.11
Python version = 3.6.5
kalani is project folder
testapp is application folder

I think my problem is in urls.py.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello

Error message:

```
 ERROR:

 Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
 Using the URLconf defined in kalani.urls, Django tried these URL 
 patterns, in this order:

^admin/
The current path, hello, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django 
settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 
404 page
```

testapp/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def hello(request):
   return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello world</h1>')
```

kalani/urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from testapp import views

 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^hello/', views.hello)
 ]
```

kalani/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'testapp'
]
```

Comment: did you try the url with trailing slash at the end ? like this : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/` is this also returns 404 ?

Comment: @shotgunner .. yes sir i have tried that also but still getting the same error..

Comment: what is your `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py ?

Comment: Make sure that you are editing `urls.py` in the project folder (the one that contains `manage.py`) and not one in the inner folder (the one that contains `settings.py`.

Comment: @shotgunner like this   ROOT_URLCONF = 'kalani.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: @Alasdair   sir  i have project folder as kalani and in that m getting urls.py in tha file m editing ...nd there is no any other urls.py in any other folder

Comment: The error message only shows a single `^admin/`, which means the server is not seeing your URL pattern for `^hello/`. Make sure you have saved your changes to the file, and restarted the server. If you are running the code on a different server, make sure you have committed and pushed the changes before restarting the server.

Comment: @Alasdair  thanks a lot sir.. it worked ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to import these urls into the variable `ROOT_URLCONF` under your `settings.py`, such as:

```
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'kalani.urls'
...
```